# Storing UserPreferences with a React Native App

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to run a few examples using react-native and was curious to see how to store User Preferences using NSUserDefaults with React Native.

Would we have to implement a module that exports the NSUserDefaults method as mentioned [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may try [AsyncStorage](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) instead?

Comment: @AustinFatheree it does not.

Answer (score 7):

I created a bridge module that interfaces with NSUserDefaults. If you still wanted or needed it (ie. you have an existing app that uses NSUserDefaults already), check it out: https://github.com/dsibiski/react-native-userdefaults-ios

:)

Answer (score 5):

React native has it own serves wrapped UserDefaults, [official site link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/settings)

```
import {Setting} from from 'react-native';

const name = Settings.get("your_id_key_can_get_from_setting_bundle");
console.log(name);

Settings.watchKeys('your_id_key', () => {
  console.log(Settings.get("your_id_key"))
})
```

Comment: That only works on iOS (If someone ends up looking general solution here)

Answer (score 3):

I've created a component to use of NSUserDefaults, it have `set` and `get` method, much easy to use, suits for storing those small, insensitive and permanent info or user preferences.

- Github: https://github.com/wwayne/react-native-user-defaults
- NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-user-defaults

Comment: Worked like a charm. Extremely easy to use. Supports both callbacks and promises. Beauty work.

Comment: Further to my own comment, check out https://github.com/kevinresol/react-native-default-preference for handling both iOS and Android.

Comment: Saved my ass, at least it works, not like AsyncStorage that has been broken on Android for over a year. Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched, but it seems like there isn't already a module for doing this, but it shouldn't be that hard to implement it by your own. This guide may help you how to implement a react-native module: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#content